# Keep display settings persistent across replugging and suspend

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 19.10, hdmi

When plugging in my external monitor to my laptop HDMI port, it defaults to "Join Displays". When I then switch to the preferred "External Only", all the various applications that were carefully placed on different desktops get shuffled up and typically most placed on one desktop. This is super annoying!

It seems to work better if I plug and replug during a single session (i.e. without suspending). Is there some way to keep the external monitor settings persistent across suspends and plugs, such that my windows don't get shuffled up every day?

FYI, this is with the Intel graphics driver, should it make any difference.

Comment: The display settings in Ubuntu aren't remembering anything. It's ridiculous, the posts here have been nonstop (and most of them, like this one, without answers). I really wish they'd fix their UX bugs.